# Best way to implement keywords or tags in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, tags

So I have a database of recipes and I want to associate keywords or tags with each meal, such
as 'Chinese', 'Italian', 'Low-card' etc.
The user never submits keywords so I have full control.
Which of the following do you think is the best approach..

A) I could have a column in the meal table filled with keywords followed by commas.
Italian, healthy, etc. Then I could grab the results from a single row on a single column and then use PHP to parse the results and do the heavy lifting.

B) I could have a keyword table with each row containing the meal_id then a single keyword. I could then query for all keywords with that id.

Or is there a better way to do implement keywords such as a fulltext??

Comment: Do you need to search for all meals with this keyword?

Comment: Yes, it would have to match any meal with that keyword and I will then show the user the meals associated with them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you with keywords mean something like tags, that are used on many sites, here on StackOverflow for instance. Then you would have three tables. One table with the meals, one table with the keywords, and one table to link both of them together. That way you can efficiently list all meals associated with a certain keyword, with a simple SQL-query.

Comment: Yes. Actually this is your best option. This creates a many to many relationship cuts down on redundancy.

Comment: So many good answers, but I like the explanation Christofer. I was thinking this route but it's always good to ask the experts!

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely use a separate table for keywords to ensure your database is normalized.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely go with B. This is the more normalized option and will be the easiest to work with. Otherwise your code will have to parse the query results.

Comment: Provided that for Option B *keyword* means an ID to another keywords table.

Comment: I don't think that is what he meant, but I agree. The best answer is to have an associative table between `meal` and `keyword` like `meal_keyword` that contained the ids to `meal` and `keyword`.

Answer (score 0):

B is better for when you'll search by tag is will be trivial task. With A you'll have to work much harder. Also with B you can always get comm-separated tags by using GROUP_CONCAT(tag)